# How does an Ethereum wallet recover the list of assets it holds when restoring from a seed phrase?

Tags: wallets, recovery

If a wallet is restored from a seed phrase, how does it discover the list of assets, for example ERC-20 and ERC-721 tokens, that the wallet holds? What if these assets are obscure, and aren't supported by services like OpenSea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wallets like Metamask have a list of tokens to check when importing a wallet. All tokens outside of this list won't be shown on the UI, hence the 'Import Tokens' option.